# Appium:Android WebView Chrome Tab Elements Not Returned In Page Source

Tags: android, webview, appium, appium-android

In android emulator having set the compatible chrome and chromedriver, I'm not able to find web-elements?
Certain pages of my app loads in chrome custom tab, and I get following available contexts on loading such a page:

```
[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.google.android.gms, WEBVIEW_app-pckg, WEBVIEW_chrome]
```

On switching to `WEBVIEW_chrome`, I'm getting more than 1 window handles. I iterate through each one of them to find my element. But all goes for a fail here, after switching contexts and searching all available windows, I'm not able to window with my expected page source.

Do I need to get some property enabled for webview debugging? I've discussed regarding setting `getWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` as `true`, but as per my dev this property can be associated with app specific web-views `WEBVIEW_app-pckg` and not the chrome tab one.

**Chrome driver logs:**

> [debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'starting'
>
> [Chromedriver] Set chromedriver binary as:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Killing any old chromedrivers, running: pkill
>   -15 -f "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver.*--port=8000"
>
> [Chromedriver] No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Cleaning any old adb forwarded port socket
>   connections
>
> [Chromedriver] Spawning chromedriver with:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver
>   --url-base=wd/hub --port=8000 --adb-port=5037 --verbose
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Chromedriver version: '2.33.506106'
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Webview version: 'Chrome/63.0.3239.111'
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'online'
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'stopping'
>
> [debug] [Chromedriver] Changed state to 'stopped'

**Appium Version:** 1.7.2, **Platform:** 7.1.1